# What is the best way to add the captured image inside RecyclerView?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-camera

I am showing all images from the user device inside `RecyclerView` using [MediaStore](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore?hl=en) and I am passing `List<GalleryModel> galleryModelList = new ArrayList<>();` to adapter via constructor.

**GalleryModel looks like**

```
public class GalleryModel {

    private final String bucketId, path;

    public GalleryModel(String bucketId, String path) {
        this.bucketId = bucketId;
        this.path = path;
    }

    public String getBucketId() {
        return bucketId;
    }

    public String getPath() {
        return path;
    }

}
```

The value of `bucketId` variable who inside `GalleryModel` comes from `MediaStore.MediaColumns.BUCKET_ID` and the value of `path` variable comes from `MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA`

**Here is the UI**

[image]

**This is the code when clicking on the New Image button**

```
GalleryFragment.activityResultLauncher.launch(new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE));
```

**GalleryFragment looks like**

```
public class GalleryFragment extends Fragment {

    public static ActivityResultLauncher<Intent> activityResultLauncher;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        FragmentGalleryBinding fragmentGalleryBinding = FragmentGalleryBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false);
        
        activityResultLauncher = registerForActivityResult(new ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult(), result -> {
            if (result.getResultCode() == RESULT_OK) {
                Bitmap bitmap = (Bitmap) result.getData().getExtras().get("data");
            }
        });
        
        return fragmentGalleryBinding.getRoot();
    }

}
```

**What I'm looking for?**

The `New Image` button will capture a new image using the camera and return the image as `Bitmap` to the app.

I want to show captured image via camera inside `RecyclerView` but I don't know how to do it because I'm not storing the captured image in the device, It is a temporary image, So I don't know how can I get details of the captured image such as `bucketId` and `path` until I can add it to `RecyclerView`.

What is the best way to add the captured image inside `RecyclerView`?

Comment: As there is no bucket id and no path and you have only a bitmap your bitmap does not fit in your GalleryModel.

Comment: @blackapps But I don't know what is the solution or alternative

Comment: Take a picture with the Camera that gives you a file. Then you have a file name and a file path.

Comment: @blackapps I don't want to store pictured image in device of user

Comment: You can add a Bitmap variable to your GalleryModel. It is always null except when you add the bitmap.